# VS2019 project from template has all files marked ignored and many syntax errors in code file

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I Exported my working VS2019 project to a template. No errors. I closed VS, reopened it and created a new project from that template. ALL the files shown in Solution Explorer (including the solution) have a red icon indicating "ignored". When I opened my .cpp file, I saw hundreds of syntax errors, so I did a Clean Build. That cleared the syntax errors, but I am still seeing the "ignored" icons. I am NOT using git or any other source control. How can I clean up the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting NONE for "Tools/Options/Source Control/Plug-in", letting VS close the solution, then closing and re-opening VS solved it for me (and removed the "ignored" flags as well). VS2019.